# how to access data in query after casting it to array in model

Tags: laravel-5

I am using laravel v5.2
when I tried to make my table columns data type Json that cause an error because of MySQL version.
I read a solution about this I can make its type text and casting them in my model to the array like that

```
protected $casts = [
        'division1' => 'array',     
    ];
```

in my controller this my query

```
$devision= admin_panel::find(1);
```

when  `dd($devision->division1);` the result is null but when I removed the casting it return the result with no proplem 
I tried this   `$devision= admin_panel::find(1)->toarray();`
but also   `dd($devision['division1']); returns null`

Comment: Do you have an example of the value in one of these columns?

Comment: yes i have the table contains only one row and this the value in one of its columns
"Dashboard
Dashboard1
Dashboard2
Dashboard3
Skins
What's New"

Comment: Well there’s your first problem, that literal string is not an array or a JSON encoded string either. That is likely why you get nothing back when trying to cast it to an array.

Comment: it's from text type saved in database in this form